# Can't compile because valac not found, but it's installed

Tags: linux, compile

I'm trying to compile gwibber. This is what happens when I type ./configure.

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for valac-0.14... no
configure: WARNING: No Vala compiler found.  You will not be able to compile .vala source files.
configure: error: "No valac compiler found."
```

But this is what I get when I type `valac --version`

```
Vala 0.15.0
```

So, I do have the right version of valac, right? How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 4):

Install libvala-dev? Depending on your distribution, your command may be different, but in my case it would be on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libvala-0.12-dev
```

[image]

If you are on Debian based linux then just do

```
sudo apt-cache search libvala
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install libvala-dev
```

and it will usually download the latest version.

[image]

Comment: I tried apt-get install libvala-dev and it said itw as already at the newest version. Then I tried apt-get install libvala-0.12-dev and it installed something but didn't have any affect.

Comment: It looks like you're needing an older version. You have 0.15 installed but it's looking for version 0.14.

Comment: How do I install this on fedora?